# How can I get a Portlet Category

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am doing a list of portlets in the java side for a portlet that they belong to a specific category, defined into the liferay-display.xml file.

I have all the installed portlets (with PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets()), but I don't know how to get their category for the filter.

Can anyone help me please?

I am using Liferay 6.2

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in **[add_application.jsp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/dockbar/add_application.jsp)** file. You'll got your answer.